# How to write IF-THEN- DO statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I have the code as below in SAS,

```
if accountopendate >= 201516 and accountopendate <= 201982 and net_worth_grp_hist >= '7.50mm-75mm' and hh_aum_grp_hist = '5.10mm-20mm' then
    do;
        net_worth_grp = net_worth_grp_hist;
        hh_aum_grp = hh_aum_grp_hist;
        aum_nw_time = 201904;
    end;
else if accountopendate >= 201516 and accountopendate <= 201982 and net_worth_grp_hist_1 >= '7.50mm-75mm' and hh_aum_grp_hist_1 = '5.10mm-20mm' then
    do;
        net_worth_grp_1 = net_worth_grp_hist_1;
        hh_aum_grp_1 = hh_aum_grp_hist_1;
        aum_nw_time_1 = 201906;
run;
```

Can anyone please help writing case when statements in SQL.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: see the examples section here: https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0202239.htm

Comment: The `do;` needs an `end;` You should do it the same way as you did in the `if`. So also and `end;` at the end of that block.

Comment: You appear to be modifying 6 variables so you need 6 separate case clauses.

Comment: You technically can do this in SQL but really shouldn't. It's a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
proc sql;
  create table output as 
  select input.*
    ( case 
        when (
          accountopendate >= 201516 and accountopendate <= 201982 
          and net_worth_grp_hist >= '7.50mm-75mm' and hh_aum_grp_hist = '5.10mm-20mm'
        ) then
          net_worth_grp_hist
        when (
          accountopendate >= 201516 and accountopendate <= 201982 
          and net_worth_grp_hist_1 >= '7.50mm-75mm' and hh_aum_grp_hist_1 = '5.10mm-20mm'
        ) then
          net_worth_grp_hist_1
        else . /* missing ? */
      end ) as net_worth_grp
/* ... hh_aum_grp, aum_nw_time, etc the same way */  
  from input
  ;
quit;
```